# I made a table with a loop, but I want to create a click event in each cell

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string empCode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EMP_CODE"].ToString();
        string empName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EMP_NAME"].ToString();
        string gradeCode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["GRADE_CODE"].ToString();

        tr = new TableRow();

        td = new TableCell();
        td.Text = empCode;
        tr.Cells.Add(td);
        tableButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        tableButton.Text = empCode;

        td = new TableCell();
        td.Text = empName;
        tr.Cells.Add(td);

        td = new TableCell();
        td.Text = gradeCode;
        tr.Cells.Add(td);

        table1.Rows.Add(tr);

    }
```

This is my code.

Here, whenever a cell is created in the table, I want to give a click event to each cell. What should I do? Please.

Comment: `td.Attributes.Add("onClick", "clickHandler");`

Comment: You should use Gridview control to display data in tabular format. It offers templating of cells so that you can add buttons or links to the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider these are dynamically created content, one way to do this is to bind a single eventlistener to the table and manipulate the event capturing mechanism to get the cell content.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table')

table.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if(event.target.tagName === "TD") {
    console.log(event.target.innerText)
  }
}, {capture: true})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I know why do you use ```{capture: true}``` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dynamic html and add in InnerHtml of the a server side control.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table id="table1" runat="server">
        </table>
    </div>
</form>

string html = "";
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string empCode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EMP_CODE"].ToString();
    string empName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EMP_NAME"].ToString();
    string gradeCode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["GRADE_CODE"].ToString();

    html += "<tr>";
    html += "    <td onClick='MyOnclickEvent()'>" + empCode + "</td>";
    html += "    <td onClick='MyOnclickEvent()'>" + empName + "</td>";
    html += "    <td onClick='MyOnclickEvent()'>" + gradeCode + "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
}
table1.InnerHtml = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

couple of ways.

1. Add click event listener for  in your table and handle it.
2. Do the following - not the efficient way, but still you can get it done.

Iterate your table rows and cols, and assign click listener.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < table1.rows.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < table1.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
              table1.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
              alertCellCOntent(this);
           };
        }
      }
    
 function alertCellCOntent(cell) {
   alert(cell.innerHTML);
 }
```